# Fourier transform of a logarithm

Tags: logarithms, fourier-series

How can one go about computing the 2d (or 1d, in either variable) Fourier transform of the function
$$\ln(w^2-k^2)?$$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Before this was migrated from physics I'd posted the same question, but with a little motivation here
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572080/difficult-fourier-transform